# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.codename1.ui.Graphics.drawShape(Lcom/codename1/ui/geom/Shape;Lcom/codename1/ui/Stroke;

Tags: codenameone

I'm following the developer guide pdf in the section describing how to paint an analog clock.
I'm getting the error in the title (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.codename1.ui.Graphics.drawShape(Lcom/codename1/ui/geom/Shape;Lcom/codename1/ui/Stroke;).

This didn't happen when I tried from intellij but does happen from NetBeans.
In intellij, simply nothing showed on the component.
I'm setting the component as the center component of a border layout in a Form.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full error text? Are you getting the error in the NetBeans console?

Comment: I ran into a similar error in NetBeans 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.codename1.push.Push.getPushKey()Ljava/lang/String;
Something that has been woring all this while.

Comment: The full stack trace code:
The full stack trace code:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.codename1.ui.Graphics.drawShape(Lcom/codename1/ui/geom/Shape;Lcom/codename1/ui/Stroke;)V
 at com.ebay.cn1.no.gui.builder.DrawingCanvas.paintBackgrounds(DrawingCanvas.java:43)
 at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:1218)
 at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:1175)
 at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.paintDirty(CodenameOneImplementation.java:382)

Comment: Continue:
 at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.paintDirty(JavaSEPort.java:978)
 at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:993)
 at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:920)
 at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
 at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)